# Server 2008R2 copying big files freezes in the middle

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, copying

Copying a big file (5GB or more) from a UNC path to a local disk freezes/stops more or less in the middle of the process. There is no way to cancel the task (if I try to do it it wall just go on the endless "cancelling" mode), the only way to stop it is to kill it or restart the whole server.

[image]

I tried to copy between the server's local folders and there are no issues. This is the only server that is having this issue if I copy from the UNC path. What is more interesting that if I copy from the server to the same network share (othere way around) there're no problems.

I tried to re-install the latest NIC drivers. This didn't help.

Then I run the server in "Safe mode with networking" and the first 2 copies were done correctly and the following tests ended up with the same issue.

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a broken AV to me, have a look at the taskmanager (ressources). I would recommend using a frequently flushing (unbuffered) copy tool like `robocopy /J`. If there are any write problems, robocopy will tell you, if it's read (and cache) problems, it will so, too.

Comment: By saying AV you mean antivirus? I checked robocopy but there's no /J switch that can be used in the version that is installed. I tried xcopy with this the same switch and the copying just seesm stuck again.